# Provide live graphs in review to motivate people

Tags: feature-request, review, graphs

I think we all liked [Shog9's graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223605/142717) for the close queue..

[image: closed queue graph]

I also think that if we would have live graphs like the one above or something that would show in the same graph how many questions are ending up in the queue per day and how many are actually being closed it will be more interesting and will motivate people to actually beat it.

One other example is Reddit. When somebody learned that [despite having 70+ million viewers, Reddit is actually not profitable and in the RED...](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/1onx27/til_that_despite_having_70_million_viewers_reddit/) everybody start buying more gold to random people just to help. Reddit [responded](http://www.redditblog.com/2013/10/thanks-for-gold.html) with a nice 
**daily reddit gold goal** thermometer, which I believe since that day, they are not on RED just by showing it to the readers :)

[image: daily reddit gold goal]

---

So my wish is to have some cool graphs that [Shog9 did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223605/142717), but live and interactive (not necessarily the one I posted above, that was just an example).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we should provide graphs in the close review queue. Yes, it would work in our favor currently with the fuzzy queue going on.

However, once it gets lowered to like 3 stars, it will probably work to demotivate people instead of motivating them.

I'll still do my 40 reviews every day (*unless for some reason I can't*), but I don't think this feature request would add anything helpful to the site.

I'd rather have Shog9 working on new ways to attack the close vote queue, then working on implementing these types of graphs.

EDIT :

I guess the only graph I wouldn't mind, would be 1 goal graph like the one you pictured with reddit.

Just a simple horizontal bar graph from left to right or vertical top to bottom. From 0% to 100%. It should say somewhere near, that there is ***N*** amount of time remaining to reach the goal.. (*which would be the amount of time till the end of the day UTC*)

The graph's 100% goal, should be ***N*** amount of total reviews that we want done each day. Maybe 5000? That number could possibly change on  a day by day basis, depending on how things go, and what day of the week it is (*to account for slower/faster days*).

Comment: I wasn't talking about that specific graph but graphs in general.. any kind that would make sense to have a more _live_ feedback.. having a daily goal as community is not a bad thing either..

Comment: I doubt it would be any more demotivating than the 120k reviews remaining figure that we already show. I don't care whether or not it's graphical it'd just be nice to see 3000 questions in, 2500 questions out today rather than just seeing 120k in the morning and 120.5k in the evening.

Comment: I don't, but AFAIK they're not going to fuzzy the number forever, in a month or so it'll be back at 120k+(+++) right? Maybe I'm wrong, but still replace 120k with 30k in my previous comment then